# I get The Subscriber Key / Customer Key was not specified in the request

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm SDK php. It looks like it is connect to my app. Alas in the end it gives me an error

> ET_Post Object ( [status] => [code] => 200 [message] => [results] =>
>   Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [StatusCode] => Error [StatusMessage]
>   => The Subscriber Key / Customer Key was not specified in the request. [OrdinalID] => 0 [ErrorCode] => 12015 [NewID] => 0 [Object] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [PartnerKey] => [ObjectID] => [EmailAddress] =>
>   test@test.com [Lists] => stdClass Object ( [PartnerKey] => [ID] =>
>   xxxx [ObjectID] => ) ) ) ) [request_id] => [moreResults] => )

Here is my code. It is simple

```
<?php
require('SDK/ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$authStub = $myclient;
$objType = "Subscriber";
$props = array("EmailAddress" =>"test@test.com","Lists" => array("ID"=>1111));
$response = new ET_Post($authStub,$objType,$props);
print_r($response);
?>
```

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried passing the SubscriberKey in your request?  More info: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscriber_key/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to declare the SubscriberKey as well...something like this maybe:

```
<?php
require('SDK/ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$authStub = $myclient;
$objType = "Subscriber";
$props = array("SubscriberKey" => "XXXXXXX","EmailAddress" =>"test@test.com","Lists" => array("ID"=>1111));
$response = new ET_Post($authStub,$objType,$props);
print_r($response);
?>
```

Comment: Yes thank you I had figured out it worked beautifully. Thank you Rob

Comment: Hey @adlan, welcome to SFSE! Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue :)